# Nullable belongsTo relationship in ember-data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember-data v1.0.0-beta.3, active model serializers and the DS.ActiveModelAdapter. I have a model that looks something like this:

```
App.Listing = DS.Model.extend
 title: DS.attr()
 pickupAddress: DS.belongsTo("address")

App.Address = DS.Model.extend
  listing: DS.belongsTo("listing")
  address: DS.attr()
```

I want the pickupAddress field to be optional, and my JSON for /listings/{id} looks like this:

```
{
  "pickup_addresses":[],
  "listing":{"id":2,"title":"Foobar", "pickup_address_id":null}
}
```

However, ember-data doesn't like this, it gives me this error:

> Assertion failed: No model was found for 'pickupAddress'

Does it support this scenario? Is there some option I can pass to the belongsTo? Or should I create some custom adapter?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your payload, the sideloaded data need to match a class name, in your sample you have `pickup_addresses`, the correct is `addresses`:

```
{
    "addresses": [],
    "listing": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Foobar",
        "pickup_address_id": null
    }
}
```